# Chain eloquent query builder method to find()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to chain an eloquent query builder method like `where` to method like `find`? For example:

```
Model::find($id)->where('slug', $slug);
```

The idea here is not to call `where` twice like this:

```
Model::where('id', $id)->where('slug', $slug);
```

Comment: `find()` method gives you a model instance, where the `first()` method do the same thing. May be you want this `Model::where('id', $id)->where('slug', $slug)->first();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just reverse the order

```
Model::where('slug', $slug)->find($id);
```

but it doesnt make much sense since the id is unique by itself.

Comment: Is there a reason for this restrictive placement? If I have a query Model::join(another table)->find($id), it's not so clear that the find is referring to the original model. Model::find($id)->join(another table) would make so much more sense.

Comment: @maganthro keep in mind that `find()` replaces two instructions: `->whereKey($id)->first()` so in that way it makes sense in this context `Model::whereKey($id)->join(another table)->first()`